# Vector spaces Base and its subspace Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I have a vector space $V$ and a subspace as described.

$$V = F^n,  W = \{(a_1,...,a_n) | a_1 + ... + a_n = 0\}$$ 
I need to find a Basis for $W$ and than expand it to be Basis for $V$
thanks for the help.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first observe that, solving $a_1 + \cdots + a_n = 0$, we obtain:
 $$a_n = t_n, a_{n-1} = t_{n-1}, \cdots , a_2 = t_2, a_1 =-t_n-\cdots-t_2$$
All the vectors of W are of the form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    -t_n \cdots -t_2 \\
    -t_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    -t_n
    \end{pmatrix}$$
That can be written in the form:
$$t_2\begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \vdots \\
    0
    \end{pmatrix} + t_3\begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \vdots \\
    0
    \end{pmatrix} +\cdots +t_n\begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \vdots \\
    1
    \end{pmatrix} $$
So all the vector of W can be written as a linear combination of 
$$\{\begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \vdots \\
    0
    \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \vdots \\
    0
    \end{pmatrix},\cdots,\begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \vdots \\
    1
    \end{pmatrix}\} $$
that is a base for W. Can you go ahead now?

Comment: You wrongly presume that all $t$ are non-zero.

Comment: Why? If all the $t$ are zero we obtain the zero vector that is in $W$

Answer (score 1):

Since you have $n$ varibles and only one equation, subspace W has dimension $n-1$.

You can find a basis for W by the $n-1$ conditions:

$$\begin{cases}a_1=-a_2=1, \quad a_3=a_4=...=a_n=0\\a_2=-a_3=1, \quad a_1=a_4=...=a_n=0\\...\\a_{n-1}=-a_n=1, \quad a_1=a_2=...=a_{n-2}=0\end{cases}$$

that is

$$\begin{cases}v_1=(1,-1,0,...,0,0)\\
v_2=(0,1,-1,...,0,0)\\
...\\
v_{n-1}=(0,0,0,..,1,-1)\end{cases}$$

Then you can extend this basis to V looking for a vector wich do not satisfies the given conditions, e.g.:

$$a_i=1\neq0$$

that is

$$v_{n}=(1,1,1,..,1,1)$$

Comment: That’s not right. Define for $n$ even, $a_1\neq0$ and $a_2\cdot -a_1$, $a_3=2a_1$ and $a_4=-2a_1$ etc.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe sorry, are you referring to the second part?

Comment: In my example the dimension of $W$ is $1$.

Comment: W has dimension 1?

Comment: Yes, because $a_2,\dots a_n$ are multiples of $a_1$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I've added some detail and fixed a value for the basis vectors, am I correct now?

Comment: Sorry everybody, I’ve misregarded the $a_k$ as vectors rather than elements of $F$.  In the latter case $W$ is a hyperplane which has dimension $n-1$. To see this take a look at the basis which gimusi or edo1988 gave.

Comment: Finally we have clarified the misunderstanding, that’s good! Bye